# Problems with LESS Sublime Text Build System

Tags: node.js, less, sublimetext

On OS X 10.7.2, I created a small build system in Sublime Text 2 that will compile my LESS files into CSS for me, but it seems to be having a problem.

```
{
    "cmd": ["/usr/local/lib/node_modules/less/bin/lessc", "-x", "$file", "$file_path/$file_base_name.css"],
    "selector": ["source.less"]
}
```

I've installed Node.js v0.6.6 using the standard OS X installer package, and installed less v1.1.6 using npm into the `/usr/local/lib/node_modules` folder. Switching to my build system works fine, but when I attempt to run the build I get the following error message:

```
[Finished]env: node: No such file or directory
```

Running the command from the terminal works perfectly fine, it's just Sublime that is taking issue.

Comment: lessc expects to have node under /usr/bin
I ran in the same problem, so I just created a symlink and worked for me:
´´´sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/node /usr/bin/node´´´

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another way to solve this is to install LESS globally, as it looks like you've already done:

```
npm install -g less
```

Then pass shell=true as a variable in the build script:

```
{
    "shell" : true,
    "cmd": ["lessc", "-x", "$file", "$file_path/$file_base_name.css"],
    "selector": "source.css.less"
}
```

That runs the **lessc** command in the terminal in a way you'd expect.

Answer (score 2):

While I am still unsure as to why there is a difference between Sublime Text 2 and running the build system in the terminal, I fixed the issue I was encountering by explicitly adding the value of `$PATH` to my build system.

Acting on the documentation provided on the [Sublime Text Help](http://sublimetext.info/docs/en/reference/build_systems.html#troubleshooting-build-systems) page, I set up my build system to be the following:

```
{
    "cmd": ["/usr/local/lib/node_modules/less/bin/lessc", "-x", "$file", "$file_path/$file_base_name.css"],
    "selector": "source.css.less",
    "path": "/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin: No such file or directory"
}
```

Comment: you should change the output name to $file_path/$file_base_name or it will output style.css.css

Comment: The path as seen by Sublime clients is not the same as the one that you set up in the terminal.  It has never sourced your bashrc or cshrc or what have you.

Comment: On Windows the path to lessc will be:
`"C:\\Users\\[USERNAME]\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\lessc.cmd"`

Comment: @taiidani - instead of adding the path follow this [tutorial] (http://tech.diaslopes.com/?p=112)
 
`ln -s /opt/local/bin/lessc /usr/local/bin/lessc`